# Adding A SDL2 Element to the Emscripten Fullscreen Element

Tags: javascript, html, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I was thinking it would be cool if one could refactor [timhutton's code](https://github.com/timhutton/sdl-canvas-wasm)'s code (which would be my SDL2 code) into [emscripten's fullscreen.cpp](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/test/test_html5_fullscreen.c) file. I tried it out, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to refactor my code. How would I start to do that? In addition, how would I run the code through two files? (i.e. one file for the fullscreen.cpp and one file for my SDL2 project's code) I'm fairly new to C++ so please be patient.

After trying to configure and refactor, when I clicked "f" the program responded, but didn't full screen.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*